# Pointer to pointer assigned to a two-dimensional array, points to wrong address

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C and although I thought I pretty much got the whole logic concerning pointers and arrays I've come across an issue that doesn't make any sense to me.

Consider a **2D array**, say

```
double arr[][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
```

and a **pointer to a pointer**

```
double ** ptrptr;
```

Now, let's say printing the address that `arr` and `arr[0]` point to, respectively, i.e.

```
printf( "%ld \n", (long) arr);
printf( "%ld \n", (long) *arr);
```

yields something like

```
140734902565640
140734902565640
```

since the first element of `arr`(array of arrays) and the first element of `*arr`(array of doubles) have the **same location**. So far so good. Now to my problem:

I do this:

```
ptrptr = (double **) arr;
printf( "%ld \n", (long) ptrptr);
printf( "%ld \n", (long) *ptrptr);
```

and I would expect the same output as before, but *instead* I get something like

```
140734902565640
4607182418800017408
```

So it seems that `ptrptr` and `arr` both evaluate to a pointer to the same location - as expected - but `*ptrptr` and `*arr` do **not**. Why?
Also, if I dereference once more, i.e. `**ptrptr`, I get a segmentation fault.

My logic went sth. like this, loosely speaking:
`ptrptr == arr == &arr[0]` should point to
`*ptrptr == *arr == arr[0] == &arr[0][0]` which in turn should point to
`**ptrptr == *arr[0] == arr[0][0]`.

Although I found a workaround that will serve my purpose, I would still really like to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: The address of an array, and the value of the array are the same (The array decays into a pointer when passed to printf). A pointer to the array and a pointer to that pointer are not the same.

Comment: Note that a double pointer != 2D array.  Multiple duplicate questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952511/c-pointer-to-2-dimensional-array) e.g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's talk about *expressions* and *types*.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

The *expression* `arr` has type "2-element array of 3-element array of `double`".  In the line

```
printf( "%ld \n", (long) arr);
```

`arr` is not the operand of the `&` or `sizeof` operators, so it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to 3-element array of `double`", and its value is the address of the first element, or `&arr[0]`.

In the line

```
printf( "%ld \n", (long) *arr);
```

since the expression `arr` has type "pointer to 3-element array of `double`", the expression `*arr` (which is equivalent to the expression `arr[0]`) has type "3-element array of `double`".  Since this expression isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `double`", and its value is the address of the first element, or `&arr[0][0]`.

In C, the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array (no separate storage is set aside for a pointer to the first element; it is computed from the array expression itself).  The array is laid out in memory as

```
         +---+
    arr: | 1 |  0x0x7fffe59a6ae0
         +---+
         | 2 |  0x0x7fffe59a6ae8
         +---+
         | 3 |  0x0x7fffe59a6aec
         +---+
         | 4 |  0x0x7fffe59a6af0
         +---+
         | 5 |  0x0x7fffe59a6af8
         +---+
         | 6 |  0x0x7fffe59a6afc
         +---+
```

So the following expressions will all yield the same *value*, but the *types* will be different:

```
Expression            Type                Decays to     
----------            ----                ---------
       arr            double [2][3]       double (*)[3]
      &arr            double (*)[2][3]    n/a
      *arr            double [3]          double *
    arr[i]            double [3]          double *
   &arr[i]            double (*)[3]       n/a
```

`*arr[i]` and `arr[i][j]` both yield a `double` value.

So now let's look at `ptrptr`:

```
double **ptrptr = (double **) arr;
printf( "%ld \n", (long) ptrptr);
printf( "%ld \n", (long) *ptrptr);
```

The first thing that we notice is that `ptrptr` is *not an array expression*, so the conversion rule above doesn't apply.  We assign it to point to the first element of `arr`, but after that it behaves like any other pointer, so the expressions `ptrptr` and `*ptrptr` *will* have different values.  Since `ptrptr` points to the first element of the array (`&arr[0][0]`), `*ptrptr` yields the *value* stored at the first element, which is `1.00`.  Just so happens that when you interpret the bit pattern for `1.00` as a long integer on this particular platform, it comes out as 4607182418800017408.

Here's some code that may make the above a little more clear:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  double arr[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
  double **ptrptr = (double **) arr;

  printf( "    arr: %p\n", (void *) arr );
  printf( "   &arr: %p\n", (void *) &arr );
  printf( "   *arr: %p\n", (void *) *arr );
  printf( " arr[0]: %p\n", (void *) arr[0] );
  printf( "&arr[0]: %p\n", (void *) &arr[0] );

  printf( " ptrptr: %p\n", (void *) ptrptr );
  printf( "*ptrptr: %p (%f %ld)\n", (void *) *ptrptr, 
     *(double *) ptrptr, *(long int *) ptrptr );

  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
    arr: 0x7fffe59a6ae0
   &arr: 0x7fffe59a6ae0
   *arr: 0x7fffe59a6ae0
 arr[0]: 0x7fffe59a6ae0
&arr[0]: 0x7fffe59a6ae0
 ptrptr: 0x7fffe59a6ae0
*ptrptr: 0x3ff0000000000000 (1.000000 4607182418800017408)
```

Again, `*ptrptr` gives us the value at the first element of the array, which is `1.0`, but we're interpreting that bit pattern as a pointer value (`0x3ff0000000000000`) and a long integer (`4607182418800017408`).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is most clearly illustrated with a diagram.

This is a normal 2D array in C, `double[4][3]`.

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

This is a double pointer in C, `double **`.  It is pointing to the head of a `double *[4]`, each of which points to the head of a `double[3]`.

```
+----------+     +---+       +---+---+---+
|          +---->|   +------>|   |   |   |
+----------+     +---+       +---+---+---+
                 |   +-----+
                 +---+     | +---+---+---+
                 |   +---+ +>|   |   |   |
                 +---+   |   +---+---+---+
                 |   +-+ |
                 +---+ | |   +---+---+---+
                       | +-->|   |   |   |
                       |     +---+---+---+
                       |
                       |     +---+---+---+
                       +---->|   |   |   |
                             +---+---+---+
```

Notice that the *syntax* for accessing elements is the same.

```
double arr[4][3];
arr[1][2] = 6.28;

double **ptr = ...;
ptr[1][2] = 6.28;
```

However, what is actually happening is quite different.  So you cannot simply cast one type to the other.

With the `double[4][3]`, you find an element by doing a little bit of math to calculate the offset.

With the `double **`, you find an element by following a chain of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

**An array can be seen as a "label":**

Unlike a pointer, it doesn't have an `lvalue`, and you cannot set it to a different value after declaring it.

Try `arr = ptrptr` or `arr = (double**)0x80000000`, and you'll get a compilation error.

That is why, for any type of array `arr`, the following is always true: `arr == &arr`.

**In addition, please note the memory-map differences:**

```
double arr[3][3]; // A consecutive piece of 9 `double` units.

double** ptrptr                // 1 pointer unit.
ptrptr = new double*[3];       // A consecutive piece of 3 pointer units.
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    ptrptr[i] = new double[3]; // 3 separate pieces of 3 consecutive `double` units.
```

So not only does `ptrptr` consume an additional amount of 4 pointer units in comparison with `arr`, but it also has the 9 `double` units allocated in 3 separate sections in memory.

**Hence `arr = &arr = &arr[0] = &arr[0][0]`, but `ptrptr != *ptrptr != **ptrptr`.**