# how to write a c function that can take both dynamic/statically allocated 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, gcc4.7

I have a function that supposed to take 2D array as an argument, my code looks like this --

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(double**, int);

int main()
{
    double m[3][3] = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}};
    func(m, 3);
}

void func(double **m, int dim)
{
    int i, j ;
    for(i = 0 ; i < dim ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < dim ; j++)
            printf("%0.2f ", m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Then the compiler says --

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  func(m, 3);
  ^
test.c:4:6: note: expected ‘double **’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[3]’
 void func(double**, int);
      ^
```

But when I say --

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    double m[3][3] = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}};
    double **m1 ;
    m1 = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * 3);
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        m1[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 3);
        for(j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
            m1[i][j] = m[i][j] ;
    }
    func(m1, 3);
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) free(m1[i]);
    free(m1);
}
```

It compiles and runs.

Is there any way I can make `func()` to take both the statically/dynamically defined 2D array ? I am confused since I am passing the pointer `m`, why it is not correct for the first case ?

does it mean that I need to write two separate functions for two different types of arguments?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/119527).

Comment: Another duplicate that might explain better: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13952511/119527

Comment: The point is, `double m[3][3]` is an array-of-arrays... all 9 `doubles` are contiguous in memory.  A `double **` is **not** a 2D array - rather it can be considered an array of *pointers*.   Reading an element in the former incurs one dereference, whereas the latter incurs two.

Comment: @OliverC this question has remote similarities with other question but is not a duplicate.

Comment: Your description is misleading. It makes no difference at all whether the array was statically or dynamically allocated. It's not clear whether you're asking "How do I have a function accept both a 2-D array and an array of pointers", or "How can I dynamically allocate a 2-D array" - although since you accepted an answer describing the latter I guess that is what you intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dynamic allocation for 2d array is not correct. Use it as:

```
double (*m1)[3] = malloc(sizeof(double[3][3]));
```

And then it will work.

Moreover change the function prototype to:

```
void func(double m[][3], int dim)
```

Another way is to use a 1-D array of size `w * h` instead of 2-D array.

[Working example](http://ideone.com/lQvdsR)

---

From comment of @TheParamagneticCroissant c99 onwards, you can also VLA's and make both your dimensions variable. (You'll need to allocate the 2D array properly though)

Change function signature to:

```
void func(int dim, double[dim][dim]);  /* Second arg is VLA whose dimension is first arg */
/* dim argument must come before the array argument */
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/g57764)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The type of `m1` is different and so is the layout.

Comment: but I can't use a variable inside the declaration, like `malloc(sizeof(int[len][len]));` right ? what if I do not want to specify `3` ?

Comment: If you want to make both dimensions variable, use the later advice (1-D array of size `w*h`) or make one dimension constant.

Comment: @ramgorur You *can* use a variable in that position, [unless the compiler defines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=195), in which case you can detect this and error out at compile-time (which you should do, because don't put up with that from your compiler).

Comment: @MohitJain in C99 and later, variable-length arrays (and pointers to them) **can** be passed to functions. No dimension needs to be constant.