# 2-dimensional array not set properly in matlab to C++ conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, matlab-coder

I have a Matlab function converted to C++ using Matlab Coder. The input is a single dimensional array of `:Infx1` and the output of matlab function is a 2-D array. I initialize this (the output) using

```
result = zeros(500,18);
```

Within my main loop I maintain a variable `count` that varies from 1 to 500 and before the end of the loop I fill the output array using

```
result(count,:) = blocks;
```

where blocks is a 18x1 vector computed in every loop.

In my converted C++ file I expect `result` to be a 2-D array. But it happens to be a vector with output given by

```
for (loop_ub = 0; loop_ub < 18; loop_ub++) {
           result[(count + 500 * loop_ub) - 1] = blocks[loop_ub];
        }
```

The initialization of `result` can be seen as

```
memset(&result[0], 0, 9000U * sizeof(real_T));
```

I cannot figure out the reason why this is not a 2-D array. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All memory is ultimately flat (1-dimensional) and you often get the best performance when interpreting it that way.  In this case, a single allocation will do (of size 500*18*sizeof(real_T)) so matlab uses it - you'll get better caching performance due to spatial locality.  The code generator could have wrapped the allocation in a multi-dimensional array type (e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116368/heap-allocate-a-2d-array-not-array-of-pointers)), but that obscures the fact that each row is actually contiguous in memory, a useful fact to know.  Otherwise, for example, it wouldn't be clear that a single memset could be used to initialize the array.